# Is there a way to test a website on a Windows as if I were using MacOS

Tags: cross-browser, cross-platform

As I have recently found out a web page can appear differently in Windows and in MacOS even if  one uses the same browser on both OS. Is there a plugin or an application that can imitate MacOS on the PC?

Comment: Emulation can only go so far. The best tests will be on the OS itself

Answer (score 1):

You may use an online tool for cross browser testing.

They're numerous.

For example :

http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ (you have to pay)

http://spoon.net/browsers/ (not working now for Safari)

https://browserlab.adobe.com/ (registration required)

disclaimer : I don't use those sites any more, I'm not sure they're good enough

Answer (score 0):

I use [Adobe Browserlab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) and [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/). Both of these services will take screenshots of any public facing URL that you enter.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#
A free cross-browser testing tool

If that isn't what you need, you can try some of the paid services
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/07/a-dozen-cross-browser-testing-tools/